# How to remote gdb debug via a jumpserver?

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, remote-debugging, clion

Here is my problem:

I got a server A , a jumpserver B and pc C with Clion IDE on it.

I want to do some debug work on A. But for some reason I have to ssh B first then ssh to A instead of ssh to A directly.

I know clion has the ability to debug C++ by gdbserver on a remote linux server. But I don't know how to do it via a jumpserver.

I am looking forward to be able to remote debug using Clion rather than using the terminal. Any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to establish an ssh tunnel through B to A. Instructions (with illustrations!) here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115897/whats-ssh-port-forwarding-and-whats-the-difference-between-ssh-local-and-remot